# How to fix ambiguous reference errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, ambiguous

I have a web app that allows importing of contacts from Hotmail, Yahoo and GMail. I finally have it almost completed but since I added the importing of GMail, I am getting ambiguous reference errors and I am unsure how to fix them without breaking any code.

Here is a screen shot of the errors:

[image: Ambiguous Reference Errors]

Comment: Write the full namespace ? Or at least enough of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to use unique class names as much as possible. This will be the better solution in the end.
2. Write the entire namespace when referencing

   ```
   OAuth.OAuthBase a = new ...;
   Google.GData.Client.OAuthBase b = new ...;
   ```
3. Make an `using` alias for one or both:

   ```
   using n2 = OAuth;
   using      Google.GData.Client;

   n2.OAuthBase a = new ...; // referenced using namespace
   OAuthBase b = new ...;    // referenced through existing `using`
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this..

```
using GoogleOAuthBase = Google.GData.Client.OAuthBase;

namespace abc
{


    public class Program
    {        
           //make sure this Google.GData.Client.OAuthBase is instansiateable
           var googleBase = new GoogleOAuthBase();
     }
}
```

2. you can try entire name space as well.

   ```
   var googleBase = new Google.GData.Client.OAuthBase();
   ```